# Can someone tell me the difference between having access via SMB vs having access via an admin account

Tags: security, smb, nessus

I am basically referring to Vulnerability Scanners(eg.Nessus) and their need for SMB ports to be enabled. If we already have a service account with an admin privileges that can read data in the registry, then why is  there a need for SMB protocols to be enabled?
Are SMB protocols something different?